# Does frequently restoring system by using Ghost damage my hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, restore, ghost

I use Window 7 SP1 and usually install many softwares for testing. I know installing many apps can make Windows slower, so I frequently restore system from a backup file by using Ghost about every 2 months.
However, my dad told me it could damage the hard drive. Is it true?
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it cannot damage a hard drive.

Hard drives for all intents and purposes, do not "wear out" and are not affected by heavy use. Excessive power cycles (spin up/down) can affect drive lifespan, but read/write activity will not.

SSDs on the other hand have limited write cycles - enough for most home users to not be concerned about - but finite nonetheless. Even on an SSD restoring every week, it should last several years.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true, if anything you are more prepared for a hardware failure of any sort, because you not only have a backup, you know how to use it, and can apply it when anything goes wrong.

Other than the total time of spin=up, and any bumping jostling, or abuse of a hard drive, other than very bad enviromental conditions, the hard drives for the most part will happily change the data on the platters over and again like (can I say that) million plus times.  The heads will wander back and forth for about as long as the motor that spins that platter will last.  Or it could die or break down at any moment.

So unless this hard drive reading and writing exceeds the Operating systems own unabated activity :-) by many many times over.  unless your drive is unnessisarily spun-up for years longer. unless your drive doing this extra work is suseptable to abuses , there is little that will change for the added activity.

Plus you have the advantages of an OS that is probably cleaner of cruft, probably more reliable, could have less viruses and malware on it :-) and will run like a dream (until it doesnt).